# Cannot copy contents of buffer into string: reading from .bin file in C

Tags: c, buffer, fread

I have a function that reads in a certain number of bytes from a file and put those bytes into a string. Using fread I can print the content of each element in my buffer, b, but if I try to print the whole string (b) nothing prints out. This is done in my code in the for loop; I print the contents of b[i]. and then after the for loop I try to print b and later put the contents of b into a structure I've created for use elsewhere.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

```
void load_frame(struct Entry P[], int framenum){
char b[256];
FILE*fp;
char *temp = malloc(256);
fp = fopen("BACKING_STORE.bin", "rb");

printf("We opened the file\n");
fseek(fp, 256*framenum,SEEK_SET);

fread(b, sizeof(b), 1, fp);

fclose(fp);
int i;
printf("Looking at the contents of buffer: \n");

for(i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
    printf("%u\n", b[i]);   

}
//Print contents of whole buffer
printf("%s",b);
//b[10] = "\0";


//Put b into char* content part of structure Entry
P[framenum].content = b;
printf("Content is: %s\n", P[framenum].content);
P[framenum].frame=framenum;

}
```

Comment: Because binary data is not the same as string data. Strings need to be NUL terminated. There is no such requirement for binary data. If you cannot guarantee that the data is a valid string then you cannot use `%s` as the format specifier in `printf`. What exactly is shown by the `%u` output? That should tell you whether the data is a valid string or not (assuming you print all the data and not just the first `10` bytes).

Comment: If I use %u I now get an address printing. I'm trying to figure out how to get the contents.  I also tried setting the last element to null by using b[10] = "/0" but that also gives me an error.

Comment: `b[10] = '\0'`. That is needs to be single quotes for char not double quotes (which is a string). But why `10`? And also, just adding a NUL does not necessarily make it a printable string. Binary data can contain non-printable characters.

Answer (score 0):

You are indirectly returning a pointer to the local array `b`.  It goes out of scope when the function returns and the value stored in `P[framenum].content` is no longer valid.  It can be overwritten by other functions because it is no longer your memory to use.

Additionally, does the buffer start with a null byte?  Does it contain null bytes?  These will terminate the string.

It isn't clear what you're doing with `temp` other than leaking memory.  However, you could make good use of it instead of using `b` (but you'd have to test that your call to `malloc()` was successful).  The calling code would have to free the memory in `P[framenum].content` when it is finished with.

You need to capture and use the value returned by `fread()`.  You need to validate that the file was opened successfully.